# correct Polymer element definition structure

Tags: polymer

Polymer noob here.  In the Polymer developer's guide, I've seen an example of element definition with the following structure:

Structure 1 (style is a child of template):

```
<dom-module>
    <template>
        <style>
          ...
        </style>
    </template>
    <script>
      ...
    </script>
<dom-module>
```

In the polymer starter kit, I see the following being generated:

Structure 2 (style is a sibling of template):

```
<dom-module>
    <style>
      ...
    </style>
    <template>
    </template>
    <script>
      ...
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Which is the better or correct structure above?  Or does each one serve a different purpose?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Structure 1 is the recommended route per v1.1.0 and above. Structure 2 comes with perf penalty but is still supported though.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/release-notes.html#release-110httpsgithubcompolymerpolymertreev110-2015-08-13